# I have installed to with gacutil my  mytext.dll assembly - but i cant access it or reference it in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, gac

How to I reference my own .dll after i add it to the GAC?
I successfully added my .dll to the GAC, have seen it in the list.
However, when i try to reference in Visual Studios..... i am lost.
Thanks Much

Answer (score 1):

The Add References dialog isn't the entire GAC ;-p

See [here](http://www.csharp411.com/adding-assemblies-to-the-visual-studio-add-reference-dialog/) for a walkthrough (I believe the steps are identical for VB and C#). Easier is to just "Browse..." to the dll you want; personally, I avoid GAC unless I *absolutely* need it, such as a COM-callable-wrapper hosted in COM+ as a "serviced component". Other than that, file references work better IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I can only second Marc on this. You don't need to reference from the GAC; you can reference it from another folder during build.